# Why isnt my discord bot answering to my messages?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I made this small discord bot to show a friend how to do it, exactly how I have done it before. But it doesnt answer my message in discord, and I cant find the error.

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('Online as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def in_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith('Hello'):
    await message.channel.send('Hello! {message.author.mention}')

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Sorry if its obvious, I just cant see it.

Comment: Are you getting a Traceback error or is the bot not set up correctly in discord?

Comment: I found the error, I wrote in_message instead of on_message. Sorry for bothering you ahh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `on_message` instead of `in_message`.
2. Format string `'Hello! {message.author.mention}'` like `f'Hello! {message.author.mention}'`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `on_message` events u can use

```
@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
   await ctx.send(f"Hello {ctx.author.mention}")
```

This is how u create actual Commands in discord.py